# Regex for strings from a, b such that each a is immediately preceded and followed by b

Tags: regex, nlp, logic

I'm trying to learn regular expressions through some practice problems I found online. The question apparently comes from Jurafsky's book on NLP and the solution cited everywhere is:
(b+(ab+)+)?

I don't think this is correct because it would leave out the possibility of strings consisting in a single b.

My proposed solution is (b+(ab+)*)? or (b+(ab+)*)*

Is my conclusion incorrect?

Question original text: The set of all strings from the alphabet a, b such that each a is immediately preceded by and immediately followed by a b.

Answer (score 0):

With your second proposed solution, you would be missing strings like "babab", and would only match strings like "babbab". With the first one, you would be matching only strings that have a single 'a'.

To handle the cases you mentioned, you explicitly want to match the strings "b" and "bb", for example, you could change the regex to "(b+(ab+)*)?"

Comment: Sorry that is what I meant. Stackoverflow is removing that asterisk. I'll escape it. I am going to edit my original post due to the typo. Isn't (b+(ab+)*)? the correct solution and not (b+(ab+)+)?

Comment: Sounds like you're correct then. By the way, I think the easiest way to learn about regexes is to play with one of the online regex testing sites. There's a lot of them out there.

Comment: Interesting. Strange that the incorrect solution is everywhere. I can plug it into one of these testing sites? What's your favorite one?

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**

The solution should be `^(b+(ab+)+)$`

**Explanation:**

I know I'm late to the party, but I am currently studying this book and stumbled upon your question.
The question is asking to capture strings where each `'a'` is immediately preceded by and immediately followed by a `'b'`.
With the test set of strings:

1. `aababaa`
2. `babab`
3. `baabaab`
4. `baababa`
5. `bbbbabbbbbbb`

The strings that should be captured are number 2 and 5.
Your proposed solutions will capture all of them since it sets the group `(ab+)` to be optional with Kleene* operator. Therefore, it will match any string that contains one or more occurrences of the letter `'b'`.
Check it on: https://regex101.com/r/jo5kmi/1

However, the cited solution requires to have at least one occurrence of the group `(ab+)`, to ensure that we match `'bab'`. So it captures only strings that have `'bab'`.

I would add the caret (`^`) and `$` sign at the beginning and the end, respectively, to the cited solution to make sure that we capture strings where each `'a'` is surrounded by `'b'`, and not to capture something like: `aaaaaaaababaaaaaaa`

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

Building upon the solutions already mentioned, I think one correct solution should be

```
\b(b+(a?b+)*)\b
```

as it allows Strings like 'bb' and 'b' as well.

## The problem I'm trying to solve is the following:

Write a regular expression for the set of all strings from the alphabet a, b such that each a is immediately preceded by and immediately followed by a b

It can be found in chapter 2 of the book 'Speech and Language Processing' by Dan Jurafsky and James H. Martin ([https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/)). I'm referencing the 3rd ed. draft.

## My interpretation of the problem is the following:

Find all Strings containing only characters from the set [ab]. Every 'a' needs to be preceded and followed by a 'b'. This definition would allow for Strings not containing an 'a'

## Explanation:

The **\b** at the beginning and the end of the regular expression stands for word boundary. Using this boundary ensures that only 'whole words' are allowed. This can be illustrated by looking at the following example:

The goal is to find the String "the", but only the String "the" on its own. We don't want it to be detected inside the words "theater" and "Athens".

**Sentence:**

I see, the theater is located in Athens.

**Solution:**

```
\bthe\b
```

Please consider that this is only a short version of the explanation, there are more details behind the **\b** operator.

In the next step we use the round brackets for grouping. This allows us to apply quantifiers on the whole group.

Starting with **b+** - This stands for at least one 'b'. Every String needs to start with a 'b', an 'a' is not allowed as the first character.

After that we open up another group using round brackets and include **a?**

The question mark stands for exactly zero or one. So only one 'a' is allowed at most. This is again followed by a **b+** as at least one 'b' has to follow every 'a'.

To allow for the String 'b' as a correct solution, we need to put a * right after the inner group. The star stands for zero or more, so the inner group does not have to be included at all.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

```
(b+(ab)*)*
```

Test strings covered:

```
"", "b", "bb", "bab", "babab", "babbab"
NOT ("a" or "ab" or "ba" or "aba" or "cbabc")
```